# What's the appropriate strategy for handling maximum memory in Java in a desktop application?

Tags: java, launch4j

I'm getting a few exceptions from my desktop application that is wrapped using launch4j about running of memory. Specifically:

```
OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Since I don't know how much RAM is in those computers, what's the appropriate strategy to minimize this sort of errors?

Are there any dangers in passing a humongous `-Xmx`, such as `-Xmx64g`? I understand my application might run out of actual physical RAM, but that's a problem the user can improve by adding more RAM, whereas having a limited maximum heap is not something they can do anything about.

But that makes me think, why isn't -Xmx essentially infinite and leave it up to the OS and the user to kill the application if it's trying to use more RAM than available.

Answer (score 1):

`-Xmx` is an important memory tuning parameter.  Generally, more heap space is better, but it's a very situational setting, so it's up to the user to decide how much is appropriate.  Obviously there are problems in trying to use a larger heap than the system has memory, as you will run into swapping.  If unspecified the JVM will use up to 1/4 of the system ram by default.

Java will keep claiming memory up to the maximum so you need to tell it where to stop.  If there was no upper limit, the heap would just keep getting bigger and bigger. The JVM doesn't clear unneeded objects from memory until the heap gets full, so "unlimited size" would mean that the heap never gets full, and just keeps growing forever and unneeded memory would never get released.

While bigger is typically better for heap, this isn't a hard rule and it will require testing and tuning to find the best amount.  It will help throughput, but can hurt latency since the bigger the heap, the longer GC pause times will be since there is more memory to clear.

Another factor is that if you have more than 32GB of heap, you need to give at least 40-42GB.  Something in the middle like 36GB will actually hurt performance and give less usable memory.  This is because for small heaps the JVM is able to optimize object pointers, but it can't do that for heaps larger than 32GB.

Note that just adding more heap isn't necessarily the solution to an out of memory error.  It can be just as likely that an improvement to the program to use less memory is feasible, and if it is that's typically the preferred solution.  Especially if your program is leaking memory somehow, more heap will just make it take longer before you get out of memory.

Comment: I can't ask the users to decide how much memory to allocate. Literally no Windows program ever asks you how much memory to allocate, you just run them and do their thing. Most of might users might not even know what memory is.

Comment: @pupeno sorry, I didn't mean the literal end user necessarily, you could have it set in your launch script or a configuration file.  You could also just leave it as the default which would be 1/4 of the system memory.  Figure out how much memory your app needs to run well, and use that as the setting.  A desktop program that will be used by many end users has different requirements than a large server that you have full control over.

Comment: Yes, that's my question, what to set it to in launch4j, if that's the correct strategy to deal with this. I wasn't aware that -Xmx is 1/4 of system memory by default. I thought it was a fixed value.

Comment: @pupeno ultimately what to set depends on the specific application and situation.  More is better, but since it sounds like this is an end user desktop application running on unknown hardware, you probably want to use as little as you can get away with (which isn't necessarily as little as possible) to minimize the impact on the user's system and lower the system requirements.  No matter what you decide on I would make it configurable for power users.